# cert-manager-webhook Certificate failed

Tags: cert-manager

I've tried to upgrade cert-manager, but CRDS are in Terminating status caused by:

```
message: 'could not list instances: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2,
  Kind=Certificate failed: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s":
  tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority'
```

How can I reissue the certificate?

I had an old version of cert-manager installed with helm (0.14) and I need to upgrade it to support k8s 1.27.
I've tried to upgrade directly but it failed, so I've tried to uninstall helm following instructions (https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/#uninstalling), but after the reinstall fails caused by old CRDS not completely removed and stil in terminating status